# Giving style template to coded domain in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, style, domains, template

I am using ArcMap 10.6.1.

Is there a way to save a style template for my coded domains in my geodatabase?

For example:

I have a feature class containing several polygon-features. When in the field, using the ArcGIS Online app, one of the things i have to choose for each polygon is the vegetation type.

I made domains so i have dropdown-menu's when working with ArcGIS Online.
What I want is the following:

- When i say a polygon vegetation type is forest (selected from the domain) I want the polygon to turn green.
- When I select heathland, I want the polygon to turn purple.

I saved the project as a `.mxd` and have the domains saved in a File Geodatabase.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to pre-populate the layers symbology so in the table of contents you see the colours against your chosen vegetation type but as no polygon has had it's  `veg_dom` set they will default to other, which should be white as in your example. As soon as you set the value for that polygon it should take on the colour in your symbology.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Tomorrow i have time to check if this works for me. Will get back to it!

Comment: Thanks again, it works. I trying to solve it using the wrong tools (trying to preset it in the domains).